# Meaning of 2 in's in shell script for loop?

Tags: shell

What does the 2nd "in" do?  I can't seem to find this kind of example anywhere other than this one right here.

```
for a in in /home/davidwright/attachments/*/*.tar
do
  echo "extracting $x"
  tar -xvf $x
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a typo. It means the loop iterates with the string `"in"` as the first value assigned to `a`, then proceeds to iterate over the results of the glob. The shell's just not that picky, and every item after the first `in` is a thing to iterate over in the `for` loop. Unless there is a file named `in` that is known to exist, `tar` will complain when it tries to unpack the non-existent `in` file.